# Customise Document Library Send to Location

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, document

I was itended to create a custom "Send to Location" in the menu for archiving purpose.
In sharepoint 2010, I have managed to setup a new option "Archive Documents" in Central Administration > General Application Settings > Configure Send To Connections, and the webservice url is something similar to this: "http://servername/Sharepoint Portal/_vti_bin/OfficialFile.asmx"

Then when I go to the document library and try to send to "Archive Documents", I get some error message like this:
***The Archive Documents site is not properly configured for this request.***

Then after I retry, I get some error ***Updates are currently disallowed on GET requests.  To allow updates on a GET, set the 'AllowUnsafeUpdates' property on SPWeb.***

Does anyone come across issue like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out one approach for the setting of customise **Send to** is on the library level. Here is the detail:

1. Go to Library Settings -> Advanced Settings.
2. In Custom Send To Destination, input targeting library name and URL

Then you will find one extra option in the send to list.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that OfficialFile.asmx requires the document routing feature to be enabled on the receiving site, try enabling the Content Organiser feature on the SPWeb.